# Don't have H.264 as a video output format option

Tags: video

I don't seem to have H.264 as a video output format option. I need it to be able to put out video in RGBA (so with an alpha channel). Tutorials on YouTube all have H.264 available, but not my Blender.

I have Blender version 2.79a

Comment: Avoid rendering to video with alpha channel. Better render to stills and apply any effects requiring alpha information first, then mix into video

Comment: If you are going to do compositing don't encode as video. Use images that support proper alpha channel (preferably as exr)

Comment: It's for short videos of maximum 200 frames.

Answer (score 1):

Choose FFmpeg Video and then it's available as codec. In 2.79 the Encoding panel has been improved, see [the release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "RGBA" option does not appear when selecting H.264. Tried al sorts of combinations. "RGB" remains the only option. My aim is to export Video in RGBA. If that is possible without H.264, that's OK.

Comment: Combination of "MPEG4" en "QT rle / QT Animation" has the RGBA option!

Comment: Unfortunately Blender says "Could not render. Possibly unsupported codec combination".

Comment: In the end, "Flash" worked. It doesn't require a codec combination.